# SKSurfaceView gets lag after stop navigation mode

Tags: android, skmaps

I have an applications and use SKMaps, I have set the SKSurfaceView with the follower NAVIGATION, This follower mode suppose to follow the device and rotate to the heading. Some time i need to draw a route and use the SKNavigationManager to navigate to some specific address, so when the device reach the destination point i stop the navigation manager and set SKNavigationFollowerMode.NAVIGATION back to the surface view, at that point the Surface view lags rendering position updates.

It seems when SKNavigationManager is stopped, resets Follower Mode on SKSurfaceView. And if i try to set Follower mode back, the SurfaceView gets lag(it's not smooth).

Thanks

This is the workflow to reproduce this issue using skobbler demo project, Also i'm using an app called Mock Locations and draw a route on it, This app will start spoofing location like i were driving.

1. Calculate a route between 2 SKCoordinates.
   1.1 configure route exposed, route listener and some other settings.
2. Configure navigation settings.
3. Start navigation with the settings on step 2.
4. Interrupt navigation at any point on the route

   4.1  Stop navigation. **SKNavigationManager.getInstance().stopNavigation();**

   4.2  Clear the current route drawn. **SKRouteManager.getInstance().clearCurrentRoute();**
5. Continue spoofing mock locations as you were diving as normal configuration. At this point you will see the maps isn't rendering smooth as normal, it's get lag, moving slowly frame by frame.

I will add some code soon.

Comment: Current SKMaps version 2.5.0

Comment: I'm not sure we understand your scenario - can you reproduce this issue in the demo project?

Comment: Yes @ando, I just checked using the the demo project. I've add some desciption to reproduce this scenario.

Comment: All right - thanks for the example, we'll look into it

Comment: @AlexSanchez: Can you please send at dev@skobbler.com the modified MapActivity class from the demo project (adding your code)? That's all that we need for reproducing the issue.

Comment: Maybe related to my problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792204/heavy-lags-in-certain-conditions - would love to get support on this issue as well.

Comment: Yes @sylviA i just sent my version to skobbler, details is on the mail. I apologize my delayed response. Thanks

Comment: @SteffenFunke The issue seems pretty similar, i have been zooming on my app and i couldn't reproduce your case.

Comment: @SylviA I create a roon to discuss skmaps related things. if you would like to join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97714/skmaps