# Heavy lags in certain conditions

Tags: android, skmaps

I use Skobbler SDK 2.5 with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 8,4 / Kitkat 4.4 and I am experiencing heavy performance issues that start after a while when dragging in certain zoom level ranges (heavy lags, frames take about 1 second to update).

Profiling shows that it seems to be GL related (`MapRenderer.render()` in GLThread takes about 500ms).

It only seems to occur in certain zoom ranges, and disappears when zooming in closely or zooming out vary far.
I guess that it also needs some time to occur, since on a fresh tablet restart it's working fine for a while. To me it looks like it lags when the zoom level is in kind of a "border" state between high detail and medium detail, but thats just me guessing.

Funny thing is that the demo App **AndroidOpenSourceDemo** is also affected, and I had the Samsung Tablet gone crash while using the app (+restart)

So I figured it might be OpenGL related, maybe some buffer fills up, and might be out of our hands, so my question is:

**Is it possible to download the old SDK 2.3**? I haven't found it in the official download channel, but I would like to give it a shot, since 2.4. introduced the change to the new OpenGL ES2 rendering engine.

Comment: No one, even from Skobbler team?

Comment: If you want to download and old version just change the url in your browser. http://developer.skobbler.com/download/SKMaps_Android_2.3.0_withDemoAndroidStudio.zip